# Php Dom Query - Get table line with td value

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I'm trying to extract a table from a website but I get a trouble. I want to keep only the line by giving a `<td>` value.
I've tried this :

```
$xpath->query("//html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/table/tr[3]/td/table/tr/td[@value('value')]");
```

But I'm getting nothing.

Anyone has an idea please ?

**UPDATE :**

I'm trying to extract from this website : http://competitions.ffr.fr/index.php/ffr/rugby_francais/competitions?ID_COMITE_T=2296&ID_PHASE=35025&NOM_COMPETITION=3DF+-+3%E8me+DIVISION+FEDERALE&ID_JOURNEE=&NOM_JOURNEE=&ID_RENCONTRE=&ID_EQUIPE=&NOM_EQUIPE=&text_joueur=&text_joueur_prenom=&text_club=&ID_CLUB=&ID_CLUB_O=&NOM_CLUB=&sans_liens=&flag_not_recherche=1&ID_POULE=49525&n_poule=1

And I want to keep the first table and get the line which contains, for example, "RC BAULOIS" or others.

Comment: Could you provide the HTML your are trying to parse?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean please- perhaps showing desired results or source data

Answer (score 0):

There are few errors in your query.

If you want the table node (which one?) then you should select that node, and not go deeper into cell level, so to get the second table from your examle:

```
$xpath->query("//table/tr[3]/td/table[tr/td[text() = 'value']]");
```

Comment: I understand but I updated my main posts wich the website where I want to extract my table.

Comment: Because your solution actually not working because I'm getting nothing

Comment: Because what you wrote is far from what you are expecting. Try this:   $xpath->query("//table[tbody/tr/td/table[//a[contains(text(), 'R C BLAISOIS')]]]");

Comment: Actually, I'm getting an error because it say the query is not valid. I've tried this : $xpath->query("//html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/form/table/tr[3]/td/table[tbody/tr/td[//a[contains(text()‌​, 'R C BLAISOIS')]]]");
Because I need to add the begin of the query in order to get the right table

Comment: Do you have some links of documentation ? Because I can't find your explanation on a doc